# Removing duplicates: python results differ from sort -u

Tags: python, list, set, duplicates

I have a very long text file (2GB) and I removed duplicates using:

```
sort -u filename > outfile1
```

and

```
>>> data = open('filename', 'r').readlines()
>>> u = list(set(data))
>>> open('outfile2', 'w').writelines(u)
```

However the two files outfile2 and outfile1 have a different number of entries:

```
wc -l outfile?
 185866729 filename
 109608242 outfile1
 109611085 outfile2
```

How is this possible?

UPDATE.
Following up on the request to see the data, I have found that python will remove as duplicates entries like:

```
 låsningernes
 læsningernes
 løsningernes
```

Effectively the second character is ignored in `sort -u`, and only the first entry is kept. Python instead does a good job of distinguishing the three records.

Comment: Inspecting a `diff -u outfile*` might give some insight into what those differences are

Comment: difficult to imagine without access to input file. Easy thing to do would be to sort outfile2 and print diff between outfile1 and outfile2

Comment: That can't possibly be the actual output from `wc`.

Comment: @JohnGordon Not sure what you mean. I added filename for comparison (as in my workflow it is in a different folder) and removed the total.

Comment: I was referring to the presence of `filename` in the output, when you only typed `outfile?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the actual output (or at least the 'extra' lines, we can only guess.

But it will come down to how much preprocessing is done by `sort`, which is finding more duplicates than `set()`.

Possible causes might be

- Trailing spaces on some lines. They might be removed by `sort` but not by `set`.
- Different handling of unicode characters. Perhaps sort maps some of them onto a smaller set of equivalents, producing more duplicates.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer as it correctly points out that it is the unicode handling.

Answer (score 0):

if you combine them and create them into a list you could do this:

```
non_duplicates= [a for i,a in enumerate(l) if i == l.index(a)]
```

this also keeps the order of the items it contains